# How to change **Touch the fingerprint sensor** test local_auth Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fingerprint

I'm using the local_auth package in my flutter app. I want to make the pop-up multi-lingual, so I changed the text using **AndroidAuthMessages**. but I'm not able to change **Touch the fingerprint sensor** and **Not recognized** text.

[image]

Code:

```dart
AndroidAuthMessages androidAuthStrings = AndroidAuthMessages(
          cancelButton: I18n.of(context).cancel,
          signInTitle: I18n.of(context).signInTitle,
          fingerprintRequiredTitle: I18n.of(context).fingerprintRequiredTitle,
          fingerprintHint: '',
          fingerprintNotRecognized:I18n.of(context).fingerprintNotRecognized,
          fingerprintSuccess: I18n.of(context).fingerprintSuccess,
          goToSettingsButton: I18n.of(context).goToSettingsButton,
          goToSettingsDescription: I18n.of(context).goToSettingsDescription,
        );
  bool didAuthenticate = await localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
       localizedReason: I18n.of(context).localizedReason,
       useErrorDialogs: true,
       stickyAuth: true,
       sensitiveTransaction: true,
       androidAuthStrings: androidAuthStrings,
      );
```

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdko6.png

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same issue and cannot change this text

Answer (score 0):

Set localizedReason: '' value when you call local_auth authenticate method.

```
await localAuthentication.authenticate(
            androidAuthStrings: androidAuthStrings,
            localizedReason: "Your text", // Set value here
            useErrorDialogs: true,
            stickyAuth: false,
            biometricOnly: true
);
```

Answer (score -3):

Set the value of  `fingerprintHint: '',` to whatever you want.
Example `fingerprintHint: 'Touch to Login',`

Comment: fingerprintHint is another text. this one does not change with this attribute ;(